Why does WindowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()) return a topInset value larger than the actual status bar height?
I’m developing an Android app and trying to get the height of the status bar using WindowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()). However, the topInset value returned is larger than the actual status bar height on my device.
Here’s my setup:
•   Device: Android 9
•   Method used: WindowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
•   The topInset returned is larger than expected, compared to the actual height of the status bar.

I’ve attached a screenshot to demonstrate the issue:

As you can see, the status bar looks normal, but the topInset value is higher than it should be. I’ve already ensured that:
•   The status bar is visible.
•   There’s no display cutout on this device.

Any advice or ideas on why this discrepancy is happening?

How did you do with the insets value?

@Kolyneh Thank you! I obtained the insets value to use it with edge-to-edge functionality, ensuring that the top components are not covered.

Yap, I mean, it looks like you used the insets value multiple times so leads that issue.

@Kolyneh The weird thing is that Android 14 devices show up as expected.

After reviewing the results of ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener, I found that when the SDK is below 30, the pixel values you receive cannot be used directly and need to be converted to DP. However, for SDK 30 and above, these values can be used as DP directly.
